# Is it possible to list UDFs in order of creation date in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I'm looking for a recent UDF, but can't remember the name of it, so if I could list them in order of when they were last modified that would help me find it.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, go to the `View` menu in Management Studio & select `Object Explorer Details`, then navigate to the `UDF` tree option you are interested in, i.e. Table-valued Functions.

The items under tha tree will appear in the `Object Explorer Details` panel, which you can order by `Created Date`.

Comment: @Graham why write SQL when you have it for free :-)

Comment: One down side to it though, any functions created in the current session are not listed - have to restart Management Studio to have it show up

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for this,

```
SELECT NAME,TYPE_DESC,CREATE_DATE,MODIFY_DATE
FROM SYS.OBJECTS
WHERE 
DATEDIFF(D,MODIFY_DATE, GETDATE()) < 7
ORDER BY modify_date DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use INFORMATION_SCHEMA datatbase.

```
Select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
where ROUTINE_TYPE = 'FUNCTION' 
order by CREATED desc
```

Above one is order by created date, if you want to order by altered date than use below.

```
Select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES where 
ROUTINE_TYPE = 'FUNCTION' order by 
LAST_ALTERED desc
```